# Getting dpkg error every time How to resolve it?

Tags: python, upgrade, dpkg

First, it was due to these python packages:

```
python-numpy
python-pandas
```

and now it is showing:

```
rutvik@rutvik-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
Suggested packages:
  manpages
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 482 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/634 kB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 36232 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your dpkg package database is corrupted.
Try this command to fix it:

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
```